# Time taken to reach the ground, curved frictionless path vs. free fall

Tags: kinematics

An object is released from rest in two conditions, one in which the object follows a straight path to the ground and one in which the object slides down a frictionless curved path. Will the time taken to reach the ground be the same in these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, NO.

You may think, that this is logical, since there is no energy dissipation, which leads to naive assumption $v=v(h)$, where $v$ is velocity and $h$ is height... This can be derived from energy law: $\Delta W_{kinetic}=\Delta W_{potential}$, which gives us $v=\sqrt{mgh}$.

BUT, this is only the expression for amplitude of velocity and not for it's direction... So if we have free fall, solution is quite straight forward $v_y=\sqrt{mgh}$. But, if we force particle to travel on some curved path with eg. frictionless curved path then ve have some  velocity in $x$ direction $v_x$. In that case $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$, thus $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}=\sqrt{mgh}$. For time needed for object to travel $\Delta h$ only $v_y$ is important. So $v_y=\sqrt{mgh-v_x^2}$. We can see, that:
$$
v_y=\sqrt{mgh-v_x^2}\leq \sqrt{mgh}=v_{free fall}.
$$
This simply means, that if object has some velocity in $x$ direction, it will fall in $y$ direction slowly.

Comment: "if object has some velocity in  direction, it will fall in  direction slowly", but in the case of an object in parabolic motion such as being released with a horizontal velocity, then the time needed to reach the ground would be the same as an object in free fall.

Comment: But in this case $v_x(t=0)$ wouldn't be 0, as can be assumed from problem statement. It's possible, that this wasn't clear. In the case that we have some $v_x$ at the begining, we should rewrite al epressions for $v$ into $\Delta v$. But I think that idea of this problem is reallly, that $v_0=0$

Answer (score 2):

**The freefall object hits first.**

The object in freefall undergoes maximal acceleration directly toward its destination, since there is nothing to slow it down. It also passes through the minimum distance, which is a straight line between its starting position and the ground directly below.

The object on the curved path must cover a longer distance to get to the ground, since the straight line is minimal. This object also has a lower vertical speed than the freefall object at all times, since the freefall object undergoes the maximum possible vertical acceleration, *g*. Since the object on the track moves slower and covers a longer distance, it will take longer to reach the ground.

You could also think about this as an energy conservation problem. As the object falls straight down, it converts gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy which comes entirely from the vertical velocity. As the object on the curved path falls, however, it must turn gravitational potential energy into both vertical and horizontal velocity. At any particular height, both the freefall and curved path objects have lost the same amount of potential energy and gained the same amount of kinetic energy, but for the object on the curved track, at least some of that energy is used in the object's horizontal velocity. After falling through the exact same height, the freefall object has a greater vertical velocity.

Answer (score 1):

No. The time to reach the ground is dependent on the shape of the curved path.

There exists a *curve of fastest descent*: the [brachistochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20physics%2C%20a,frictionlessly%20under%20the%20influence%20of). See also this [brilliant video](https://youtu.be/1BdO8J0iynY).

And vertical freefall is the fastest descend of all.

Comment: The brachistochrone curve is very interesting, but I'm not sure it applies, as it represents the curve of fastest descent for *fixed* start/end points. Here, the endpoint isn't fixed; we can move it to achieve minimal descent time. This is achieved by moving the endpoint directly underneath the starting point, resulting in a degenerate brachistochrone which is just a vertical line. The question isn't what path is fastest between two specific points (a brachistochrone), it's what path is fastest between a point and a plane (a straight line).